# Season plot in R

Tags: r, plot, forecast

I have a dataset with dates and averages which looks like that:

| Dates | AVG |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-04-01 | 29.2 |
| 2019-08-01 | 29.5 |
| 2020-12-01 | 15.6 |
| 2019-02-01 | 28.7 |
| 2020-01-01 | 16.3 |
| 2019-07-01 | 29.6 |

The Dates column was characters so I used:

```
library(lubridate)
my_data$Dates <- ymd(my_data$Dates)
```

So, now my dataset has dates format for the Dates column, and numeric for the AVG.
I want to do a scatter plot, which will connect the dots of the AVG of each year separately. So, I want to have one line for 2019 and one different line for 2020 but in the same plot.

I saw online that I can do something like that, if I use the ggseasonplot of the forecast library, but this command excpect you to have xts data and in my case only the first column is in dates format.
I tries to convert the entire dataset to a xts dataset using that:

```
library(xts)
xts_data <- as.xts(my_data)
```

but I am getting back the following error because my data are not in POSIXlt format:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I don't know how I can make my data to be in a correct format to use the ggseasonplot. Any help on that would be appreciated.
Also, any other suggestion on another way to do the plot I want (not using ggseasonplot at all), would be very much appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested by [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html), which can give nice plots quite rapidly once you get used to its syntax and logic.

To get the output of [ggseasonplot](https://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/reference/seasonplot.html) with `ggplot2`, you can use functions from `lubridate` such as `month`, to get your x coordinates and `year`, to group your observations per year.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = my_data, 
             mapping = aes(x = month(Dates, label = TRUE), 
                           y = AVG))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(group = factor(year(Dates)),
                color = factor(year(Dates))))+
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Year")+
  xlab(label = "Month")
```

[image]

If you want to show the months without data:

```
ggplot(data = my_data, 
             mapping = aes(x = month(Dates, label = TRUE), 
                           y = AVG))+
  geom_blank(data=data.frame(),
             aes(x = month(seq(ymd('2020-01-01'),
                           ymd('2020-12-01'), 
                           by = '1 month'),
                       label = TRUE),
                 y = NULL))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(group = factor(year(Dates)),
                color = factor(year(Dates))))+
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Year")+
  xlab(label = "Month")
```

[image]

Raw data

```
my_data <- read.table(header = TRUE,
             text="Dates    AVG
             2019-04-01     29.2
             2019-08-01     29.5
             2020-12-01     15.6
             2019-02-01     28.7
             2020-01-01     16.3
             2019-07-01     29.6")
```